# How to create a number or a string like ' 0000001'

Tags: javascript, numbers

How do I create a " 00000001" type number format or string in javascript, like " 00000001 0000002 00000003 ... 000000123 " and so on, can you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.padStart(targetLength [, padString])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
console.log('0'.padStart(10, '0'));
console.log('01234'.padStart(10, '0'));
console.log('0123456789'.padStart(10, '0'));
console.log('0123456789ABCDEF'.padStart(10, '0'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none;
}
```